# Matlab Calculating mean of distribution quantile in a for-loop

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, distribution, quantile

I am trying to calculate portfolio cVaR (conditional value at risk) levels from my simulated data for various portfolios.

I am able to do that for one single portfolio using the following code:

```
% Without a for-loop for series 1

test2 = test(:,1)

VaR_Calib_EVT   = 100 * quantile(test2, VarLevel_Calib);
help1           = sum(test2(:) <VaR_Calib_EVT/100);
cVaR_Calib_EVT  = sum(test2(test2 <VaR_Calib_EVT/100)/help1);
```

However, when putting a for-loop around (see following code), the output values in cVaR_Calib_EVT are wrong except for the value in in cell (1,1).

```
VarLevel_Calib           = 0.05;
test                     = trnd(3,780,16); 
nIndices                 = 16;

for i=1:nIndices
    VaR_Calib_EVT  (:,i) = 100 * quantile(test(:,i), VarLevel_Calib);
    help1          (:,i) = sum(test(:,i)<(VaR_Calib_EVT(:,i)/100));
    cVaR_Calib_EVT (:,i) = sum(test(test(:,i) <VaR_Calib_EVT(:,i)/100)/help1(:,i)); 
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Best, 
Carolin

Comment: What do you mean by "carried out correctly" ? Please be more specific on what is wrong with your output, what have you checked, etc.

Comment: Hi Ratbert, thanks for trying to help. I have adjusted my question, hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Again, can you explan the meaning of "wrong" in the sentence "... the output values in cVaR_Calib_EVT are wrong except for ..." ? You have to understand that we do _not_ know what you are trying to do and what you expect as a result. To me, your code is perfectly fine since it works without error.

Comment: By "wrong" I mean that the values in cVaR_Calib_EVT are not the ones I would obtain when running the other code extract (without the for-loop) for all 16 portfolios separately by changing the index manually. It is only the very first value in cVaR_Calib_EVT that is equivalent to value generated from the code section without the for-loop.

Comment: Try `cVaR_Calib_EVT (:,i) = sum(test(test(:,i) <VaR_Calib_EVT(:,i)/100,i)/help1(:,i));` in the last line before end

Comment: Many thanks schvaba986, your solution works perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `test` variable is a three-dimensional variable, so when you do

```
test2 = test(:,1);
```

and then

```
test2(:) <VaR_Calib_EVT/100
```

it's not the same as in your second example when you do

```
test(:,i)<(VaR_Calib_EVT(:,i)/100)
```

To replicate the results of your first example you could explicitly do the `test2` assignment inside the loop, which should perform as expected.

However note that using only two indices to specify parts of a 3-dimensional matrix will probably behave in unexpected ways and the long-term solution would be to explicitly specify exactly which members of the `test` matrix you want to include.  If you do this you will be able to safely expand your single example into the loop.